# Speed proccess of a script instead of executing code line by line

Tags: bash, multithreading

I have a bash script that do the following line by line:

1. download a list of ssl_queries from shodan like ssl:example.com
2. save it to txt file and see the live hosts by httpx
3. run port scanner on those list
4. scan the live hosts by vulnerability scanner
5. bruteforce directories with ffuf and wordlist about 100K

The problem here is that steps like using ffuf and scan the hosts by the scanner take a lot of time like 8 to 10 days for the whole scan

How can I run steps 3,4,5 concurrently to save time or is there a better method to do it?

I tried to made the script doing these steps concurrently in this code but it still execute a function then execute the next one after it finishes

```
#!/bin/bash

# Array of SSL queries to monitor
timeout_duration=1400
ssl_queries=(

    "queries"
)


# File to store new IP addresses
output_file="ips.txt"
timestamp=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H")
new_ips_file="/home/momo/monitor/new_ips_${timestamp}.txt"

# Function to retrieve and monitor new IPs
echo "start scan" | notify
monitor_ips() {
    for query in "${ssl_queries[@]}"; do
        echo "Monitoring $query"
        shodan download "$query" ssl:"$query"
        gunzip -f "$query.json.gz"
        jq -r '.ip_str' "$query.json" | anew "$output_file" | tee -a "$new_ips_file"
        
        # Run live_urls function
        cat "$new_ips_file" | httpx --title | notify | cut -d " " -f 1 | tee "fuzz_$$.txt"
        
        rm "$query.json"
        # Run portscan, execute_nuclei_command, and run_ffuf in parallel
(portscan; execute_nuclei_command; run_ffuf) &

# Wait for all background processes to finish
wait
    done
}

# Function to execute nuclei command
execute_nuclei_command() {
    while IFS= read -r fuzz; do
        timeout "${timeout_duration}s" nuclei -u "$fuzz" -t ~/nuclei-templates/ -es info -no-stdin -etags ssl -o "result_$$.txt" | notify
    done < "fuzz_$$.txt"
}

# Function to run ffuf
run_ffuf() {
    while IFS= read -r ip; do
        ffuf -c -u "$ip/FUZZ" -w wordlist.txt -ac -fs 0 -fc 500 -fr 'Whitelabel Error Page|Allowlist|The request could not be satisfied|Internal Server Error|This website is reserved for Samsung Service|invalid_grant|This application has no explicit mapping for /error' -maxtime 1800 -o "second_$$.txt"

        if [[ $(stat -c %s "second_$$.txt") -lt 31200 ]]; then
            cat "second_$$.txt" | jq -r '.results[] | [.url, .status] | @tsv' | notify
        fi
    done < "fuzz_$$.txt"
}

# Function to perform port scanning
portscan() {
    cat "$new_ips_file" | naabu -p 2075,2076,6443,3868,3366,8080,9443,9091,4080,3000,8000,5900,8081,6000,51820,10000,8181,7001,3306,65455,5000,4000,8888,5432,15672,9999,161,4044,7077,4040,9000,8089,7447,7080,8880,8983,5673,7443,19000,19080,9200,27017,5985,9042,6984,6379,2375,8983,8383,554,4990,9000,8500,6066,9160,3389,5900,23,10250,10255,30000,32767,8088,6389,4444 | notify
}

# Run the monitoring function
monitor_ips
```

Comment: move `wait` after the `for` loop

Comment: still same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
(portscan; execute_nuclei_command; run_ffuf) &
```

With one of the following:

```
# one-liner:

portscan & execute_nuclei_command & run_ffuf &

# 3 lines:

portscan &
execute_nucleai_command &
run_fffuf &
```

If that doesn't do what you want then please update the question with details on what you mean by *`run steps 3,4,5 concurrently`*